# MPEG-DASH one file with audio+video

Tags: html, mpeg-dash

Is it possible to work mpeg-dash with only file and not two files, one for audio and one for video?

If so, please explain how to decode (tool, arguments).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

MPEG-DASH does not limit you to have separate audio/video tracks (two, or even more files). However, in many scenarios this is the preferable solution - think of multi-language use cases.

Regarding decoding/playback - that's highly depending on the used player and/or decoding engine. Most modern browser's [Media Source Extensions](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) are for instance capable of handling such multiplexed content.

Comment: I use ffmpeg to dash files. I'll see how to keep it in one files. I don't need languages support. And I meant how to encode using ffmpeg. Not decode. It doensn't let me edit.

Comment: Dash.js debug message notifies it doens't support multiplexed: "Multiplexed representations are intentionally not supported, as they are not compliant with the DASH-AVC/264 guidelines". is there way around it?